# Difference-in-differences with standardized time

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I have different treatments, on different groups, that occur at different times (e.g., 2000 on treat 1, 2009 on treat 2, etc.). I want to fit a DiD model, and I want to standardize the treatment years to year "0" as the the treatment time. To control for treatment year heterogeneity, I included the true year fixed effects.

\begin{align}
y_{it} = &β_0 + β_1{\rm Treat} + β_2{\rm After} + β_3({\rm Treat} \times {\rm After}) +   \\
&({\rm pre}_3 + {\rm pre}_2 + {\rm pre}_1 + {\rm now} + {\rm post}_1 + {\rm post}_2 + {\rm post}_3) + γC_{it} + ϵ_{it}
\end{align}

Questions:

1. Is there anything wrong with this model? What should the time for the controlled group?
2. Can I still include the time fixed effect as {pre1,2,3, now, post1,2,3}?

I know there is another way of writing the multiple treatment as to just include the interaction term (which do not require time standardization): variable("Treat") equals to 1 is the treated groups in the time when  treated already, and variable("Treat") equals to 0 for controlled groups and for treated groups in the time when not yet treated.  But I need the standardized method as well.